# How to add an sklearn wrapper for a new ML algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to integrate [factorization machines](http://www.libfm.org/) in sklearn. I checked sklearn documentation and the web for how to wrap a new algorithm but this requirement seems to be not very well documented.

So, I would like to ask on whether there is a documentation on how to add a new algorithm wrapper to sklearn (besides reading the source code)?

Comment: This question is probably too broad for stackoverflow. There's a channel for `scikit-learn` on gitter. You may get more information there.

Comment: what do you mean by wrap a new algorithm?

Comment: @yangjie, I would like to be able to apply the same functional methods of like any other algorithm, fit, predict, score, etc. I would like to be able to use the same np/pandas datastructures and pass them to the new algorithm. I would like to be able to add the algorithm to a pipeline, apply gridsearchCV,etc. I simply want to leverage the ease and flexibility of sklearn to this tool.

Comment: Here's an example of a popular ML algorithm, XGBoost, wrapped in a sklearn interface:

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py

Comment: @inversion this is very helpful.

Comment: @inversion, I believe your answer is the most fit to my question. So please go ahead and put it so I accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After working through the `sklearn` documentation, the best thing to do is to look through a complete working example.

The `XGBoost` module has a thorough `sklearn` wrapper, which you can see here:

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py

Comment: Here's another link you may find useful, which wraps a libfm executable:

https://github.com/gatapia/py_ml_utils/blob/master/LibFMClassifier.py

Answer (score 0):

From this FAQ I get they are not very fond of new algorithms http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#selectiveness for reasons that seem valid. Given that, it is plausible to think that there are not any documentation on how to add a new algorithm wrapper. I will add that I've been using the package for a while now and I've never found anything either on their website or other websites that was similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: So, as a short answer you say there is no way to add a new algorithm rapper? In anyway, I do not want to force sklearn gurus to accept this extension in the source base, I will add it for my own personal use so I get the potentials of sklearn with factorization machines, I will share as a non official opensource extension though.

Comment: It's hard to confirm something is missing from the internet. What I am saying is that there is not something like that on the official website and that I have not found it elsewhere. Maybe you could track other non-official extensions on github and mail the owners.